# C# Asp.Net changing DataSource for GridView using DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, webforms

I creating a webPage to display stored data from a local DataBase. I am want to use DropDownList Item to change what columns and order by in GridView. Would it be easier to change DataGrid Datasource upon selecting from DropdownList, or Changing Query string.

All data is pulled from the same DataSource however displaying different columns and different order by.

for example:

DropdownList Selctions are (General Overview , portfolio, System Log)

upon selecting General Overview:
 GridView will display Columns([name],[Location],[Profit],[Current Standings] Ordered by Name asending From Tabel[Main])

upon Selecting Portfolio:

GridView will display

Column([name],[Current Standings],[profit],[Price Paid],[Quantity Bought],[Buy/Sell] ordered by Profit desending from Table[main])

upon selecting System Log:

gridview will display

Column([Time],[System Message],[Error Code], [Restart] Ordered by Time asending from Table[System Log])

Any Help would be greatly Appreciated!! I have searched for an answer for two days now without results. Ideas Welcome!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a combo box to change selected dataTbale. With my list items set to: "General", "Profit", "System Log". I inserted a datagrid into the form then without setting a dataSource, wrote this code on the c# side

```
private void drop1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String selI = drop1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            String strConnect = ("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\\Users\\smith\\Documents\\SqlStockDB.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
            SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(strConnect);
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcmd.Connection = Connect;
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            if (selI == "General")
            {
                sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Call Sign] AS Call_Sign, [Current Price] AS Current_Price FROM [Main] ORDER BY [Call Sign]";

                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);

                DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dtRecord);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

            if (selI == "Profit")
            {
                sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Call Sign] AS Call_Sign, [Current Price] AS Current_Price, [Profit], [Buy], [Sell], [Available Money] AS Available_Money, [Quantity Bought] AS Quantity_Bought FROM [Main] ORDER BY [Profit] DESC, [Quantity Bought] DESC, [Call Sign]";

                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);

                DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dtRecord);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }

            if (selI == "System Logs")
            {
                sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Time], [Module], [Error Code] AS Error_Code, [Restart] FROM [Error] ORDER BY [Time], [Module], [Restart]";

                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);

                DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dtRecord);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;

                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
```

Upon selecting an item from the list it will now show different set of Data on the grid without trying to call a different data source.

Comment: To change order which is shown in gridview simply move the column in the sqlCmd.CommandText to where you want it displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep the property `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`(which is default) in GridView and don't set any `<Columns>`. GridView will generate the columns which fit you datasource automatically. following as a quick example

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem>NameOnly</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>WithPosition</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1">
</asp:GridView>
```

code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "WithPosition")
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = new List<dynamic>() {
            new { Name = "Andy", LastName="Wayne", Position = "PG"},
            new { Name = "Bill", LastName="Johnson", Position = "SD" },
            new { Name = "Caroline", LastName="Barry", Position = "Manager"}
        };
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "NameOnly")
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = new List<dynamic>() {
            new { Name = "Andy", LastName = "Wayne"},
            new { Name = "Bill", LastName = "Johnson"},
            new { Name = "Caroline", LastName = "Barry"}
        };
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! from what i understand about your code: you created a list to be displayed. I am showing Data Items pulled from my data source.

Comment: I have believe instead of trying to autoset datasouce, That i can call query the datasource with a selected command string. I am currently writting script: